# How to stop a python udp_listener after certain time

Tags: python, time, udp

I have create UDP listener in python which i want to stop after a certain period in time. But due to the blocking call recvfrom() i am unable to do..

```
import socket
import time
UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 1337
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
cur_time = time.time()
count = 0;
while True:
  if int(time.time() - cur_time) > 1:
      break
  data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1500)
  print "received message:", data
  count = count+ 1
  print "received packets:",count;
  sock.sendto(data, addr)
```

Comment: hey i got it...By using socket.settimeout(value) we can stop the server

Comment: It's ok to answer your own question if you've worked it out